# Not able to resolve any imports using HERE api

Tags: java, android-studio, here-api

I followed the directions with creating a 'libs' directory etc, but I am running into a few issues:

1. "Project with path ':HERE-sdk' could not be found in project ':app'."
   This is the current issue I am running into- I am fairly new to Android Studio so following the directions on the HERE website is my only reference.

   2. There was a point where the project built and this was not an issue, but I could not resolve any import statements I needed - mainly the PositioningManager.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You look to be using it as a module, you have the source code for HERE-sdk on the path with the same module name?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean by module, but the source code is all on the same path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that the gradle is not able to locate the HERE SDK library. You could try updaing the gradle built like one of the examples available [here](https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples) to check if it resolves the issue.

Basically the libs directory should be specified and dependencies should include the HERE-SDK.aar file

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(name: 'HERE-sdk', ext: 'aar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
}
```